# Facebook Reporting Tool

Tags: facebook, google-apps-script

I'm trying to extract some data from the Facebook Marketing API to Google Sheets.

I'm using a tool created by Ritwik:

https://github.com/RitwikGA/FacebookReportingTool

But I need to make a small change, and due to my limited skills, I have a big problem with that.

Getting to a point, I need to extract data from the last 14 days divided by each day.

```
var CLIENT_ID = '' ;     // Insert App ID                                        

var CLIENT_SECRET = '';  //; // Insert App Secret

var FB_AD_ACCOUNT_ID = ''   //Ad Account Id

var FB_FIELDS = 'clicks,spend,impressions,campaign_name,adset_name,ad_name';

var FB_LEVEL = 'ad'; // ad,adset,campaign,account 

var pos = [2,1]     //Spreadsheet Cell Position

var DATE_RANGE='last_14d';    

var start_date='2017-01-01';                // custom date range
var end_date='2017-06-30';
```

I set the date range, but I have no idea how and where I should add a command to divide data by day.

Now it is shown together for the entire period.

Comment: Your question is too broad please show what would be the require result also add more code (Query code for example). Thx

Comment: Consider that you may need to query for each day individually.